# Switch Between Users

Tags: ssh, putty, user-accounts

I build my webapp on a local machine, but from time to time I can go to a public Linux server on which I have two accounts using a ssh connection (with putty). My accounts are two Linux users,  access to my public webapp is at the address: 'http://linux_srver_ip/~user_name'.

Using putty, when I'm logged as user_one, how can I switch to user_two account?

Comment: Does `user_one` has `sudo` permission?

Comment: how can I find that?

Comment: Run a command with `sudo`, e.g: `sudo /usr/sbin/visudo`.

Comment: You don't need sudo if you have the password for the second account.  To see what sudo privs a user has, run "sudo -l" to list them.

Answer (score 1):

`su <username>`

http://linux.die.net/man/1/su

Comment: I prefer "su - username".  The "-" causes "su" to invoke the login shell process, which may be important if the other user should be accessed with a different environment from the first user's.